# vector space model algorithm in Java to get the similarity score between two people

Tags: java, algorithm, vector, artificial-intelligence, text-mining

I am trying to use/implement a vector space model algorithm in Java to get the similarity score between two people based on its keywords. So I have the following classes:

Person - Has a List of keywords;

Keyword - 
String text;
Integer score;

The keyword score is the number of mentions the person has made to the keyword.

Any suggestions on how to implement this in Java?

Regards

Comment: Is there any particular reason you have to implement the VSM in Java yourself? Personally, I would use WEKA to do something like this.

Comment: There are more reasons to reinvent the wheel than homework.  I don't think that the question is entirely unreasonable.

Comment: Where in WEKA could I get the class/method capable to do this for me? Don't need machine learning here guy, just want to compare two people based on its keywords. The module that extracts the keyword(terms) already uses some machine algorithms to improve its work.

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/weka

Comment: Why do you need to use Weka? Just calculate cosine similarity (or other metric) between two feature vectors.

Answer (score 4):

Its very easy.

1. First you should create vector representation, example Map for each person representing its keywords.
2. Second you should select metric, I would recommend http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity.

So now real code:

```
  static double cosine_similarity(Map<String, Double> v1, Map<String, Double> v2) {
            Set<String> both = Sets.newHashSet(v1.keySet());
            both.retainAll(v2.keySet());
            double sclar = 0, norm1 = 0, norm2 = 0;
            for (String k : both) sclar += v1.get(k) * v2.get(k);
            for (String k : v1.keySet()) norm1 += v1.get(k) * v1.get(k);
            for (String k : v2.keySet()) norm2 += v2.get(k) * v2.get(k);
            return sclar / Math.sqrt(norm1 * norm2);
    }
```

Comment: Also, 'both.removeAll' should be 'both.retainAll', since we want to find the intersection of the two sets v1 and v2

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bug in the sample code above.  The the corrected code is below.

```
static double cosine_similarity(Map<String, Double> v1, Map<String, Double> v2) {
        Set<String> both = Sets.newHashSet(v1.keySet());
        both.removeAll(v2.keySet());

        double sclar = 0, norm1 = 0, norm2 = 0;

        /* We need to perform cosine similarity only on words that 
         * exist in both lists */
        for (String k : both)  {
           sclar += v1.get(k) * v2.get(k);
           norm1 += v1.get(k) * v1.get(k);
           norm2 += v2.get(k) * v2.get(k);
        }
        return sclar / Math.sqrt(norm1 * norm2);
}
```

Comment: Actually, yura is correct. You need to loop over each map separately when calculated `norm1` and `norm2`. This way, we can take into account the mismatches between the two strings. Otherwise, the similarities will only be calculated on the shared words, and the sim score will be falsely inflated.